# Basic HTML Positioning

Tags: html, css

New to HTML and trying to figure out why this is happening:

```css
.oaHeader{
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.logo{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.oaAccount{
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-container">
    <div class="oaHeader">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="oaAccount"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the padding on the right get ignored? How can I adjust the Page-Container so this won't happen? I want the right box to be adjusted accordingly. I know it's a basic question, I know a possible solution, but I want to know why it happens.

Comment: _“Why does the padding on the right get ignored?”_ – it doesn’t. Go read up on the _box model_ first, and then on the `box-sizing` property.

Comment: Your padding is not ignoring, this happens beacuse the width of the div is to large, and you can not see it.

Comment: It isn't ignored - if you scroll your page right you will see it.  If you want your box to be 100% with padding, add `box-sizing:border-box` to `oaHeader` - more info: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Interesting candidate to close this question.

Comment: This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The padding isn't ignored; it's just overflowing so you have to scroll to see it. Remove the `width: 100%` from `.oaHeader` and it should work:

```css
.oaHeader{
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.logo{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.oaAccount{
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-container">
    <div class="oaHeader">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="oaAccount"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the browser does the padding in addition to any width specification. So when you have a padding either side of 50px, plus a width of 100%, you're essentially saying you want a box that is 100% width, plus another 100px.

the box-sizing css property can be used to tell the browser that the padding is inclusive within the width specification. To do this, add `box-sizing: border-box` to your container element (the one with the padding on it).

You can read more about this property here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Don't worry, this catches most people out at the start, just thank yourself your learning in an age where we no longer have to support IE6 :)

Answer (score -1):

Add box-sizing property for the oaHeader. This will wrap all your div inside the header.

The box-sizing property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate width and height of the elements.

```css
.oaHeader{
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.logo{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.oaAccount{
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
  <div class="page-container">
    <div class="oaHeader">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="oaAccount"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is related to the box modal.

Comment: This is flagged as very low quality. The downvote it's not mine.